# Problema ao salvar data no banco de dados mysql com spring

Tags: mysql, spring

Estou tentando salvar uma data no banco de dados usando spring + jpa no mysql. Na minha classe eu tenho o seguinte campo:

```
@Column(name = "dataNasc") 
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@NotNull
private Date dataNasc;
```

Quando eu tento salvar por exemplo: 2020-02-11, ele salva com a hora junto. O que eu posso fazer pra remover o horario?

Comment: o date está depreciada, se for salvar sem as horas, troque por um Localdate

Comment: funcionou! valeu! Quer comentar fora da pergunta pra eu dar o voto pra sua resposta?

Comment: mandei, só dar aquele like rs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme comentado, o date está depreciado.
Para manipular datas sem as horas utilize Localdate
Se for precisar das horas utilize LocalDatetime.

Documentação.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html